# invalid compressed data--crc error invalid compressed data--length error

Tags: kvm-virtualization, gzip

I gzipped a 8.7GB kvm qcow2 image but I forgot to add the -k parameter so the original image is lost.

So in order to get it back i tried to "gunzip" and the resulting file blew up past 400GB... Afterwards giving me the following errors

`invalid compressed data--crc error
invalid compressed data--length error`

I used the `file` command on it and which does print what file was compressed

What can i do to uncompress the file?

Comment: Even sparse files would not behave that way. Maybe I/O error - you might check your dmesg and other logs. - most common mistake with guest images is to have the guest mounting it still running - so maybe that.

Comment: ah that must be my mistake rip thanks for the answer

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt i have now attempted the following:shutdown the vm copy the image to a different location, zip the image
i still notice the size exploding when attempting to unzip it